# How does the ctime function in this program work?

Tags: c, ctime, time.h

I am posting a  program that I came across. Can anyone explain me

1. What "0x7FFFFFFF" means?
2. How does ctime() function work?

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <time.h> 

int main()
{ 
     time_t Variable = 0x7FFFFFFF; 
     printf("Variable value is = %s \n", ctime(&Variable) ); 
     return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ctime` converts `time_t` value to string. From [Wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/time.h/time_t)

> time_t as an arithmetic type, but does not specify any particular type

`0x7FFFFFFF` is `2147483647` in decimal equal to 2^31 − 1. Max Value that can be represented in a 32-bit signed integer.

Answer (score 0):

`0x7FFFFFFF` is the maximum value that can be represented in a 32-bit signed integer. If `time_t` is a signed integer type then `ctime(&Variable)` represents the [**end of the world**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) on a 32-bit system. We'll go into the *undefined world* from there. ;-)

However, the *end* has been **[postponed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem#Solutions)** by the use of 64-bit types for `time_t`.

Answer (score 0):

usually ctime used in following way

```
/* ctime example */
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <time.h>       /* time_t, time, ctime */

int main ()
{
  time_t rawtime;

  time (&rawtime);
  printf ("The current local time is: %s", ctime (&rawtime));

  return 0;
}
```

We first save current time in rawtime variable using `time()` and then display it in human readable string by using `ctime()`